# Extracting a substring from a weird larger string (repeated characters)

Tags: java, string

I have a series of address lines in the format: 12345 Some Address, Some Square|phone number|surname name

For example:

> 40327 Ocie Camp Apt. 117, Maywood|1-155-932-2562 x738|Sauer Meredith
>
> 76106 Tomas Highway, Santa Ana|722.884.5632|Roberts Westley 19056
>
> Jamarcus Lane, Lawndale|(151)847-7455 x133|Haag Camille 66724 Slip
>
> 12-C, Hoover|841.047.3195 x69422|Trantow Danielle 99824 Fisher Locks
>
> #247, Akron|(565)132-9970 x93939|Wiza Bell

I'm trying to extract the surname part only.

I've tried the typical str.substring(str.indexOf("|"), str.indexOf(" ")), but obviously this leads to the wrong string being extracted.

Any ideas as to how I'd get the surname out of strings like those?

Comment: is there in all that "weird string" more than one surname???

Comment: Edited it - they're meant to be separate lines. One surname per line.

Comment: This is a delimited String so split the String an take the correct cell : `s.split("|")[2]`. Then, to get the Surname only, you can't because a surname can have a space

Comment: Have you tried using a regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is consistent defined in a form that you have ALLWAYS a data structure like:

> "12345 Some Address, Some Square|phone number|surname name"

then you can split every line to the pipe char and get the element at index 2

```
String myString = "12345 Some Address, Some Square|phone number|surname name";
String[] x = myString.split("\\|");
System.out.println(x[2]);
```

## Edit:

if some elements change its order this approach is not going to work, if some elements are missing this approach is not going to work, so you need to take care of that validating the input before..

## Edit2:

another approach can be getting the last index of the pipe **|** and truncating with **String#substring()**

```
int c = myString.lastIndexOf("|");
System.out.println(myString.substring(c + 1));
```

Comment: You could use the int parameter in the split method to force the size of the result. This will at least prevent the OutOfBoundsException in case of a shorter String. Has I said in comment, this will return the couple `surname name`, not `surname` but there is no solution to get only the surname without adding a constraint on the accepted data or a delimiter.

Comment: This works well enough. Data is always consistent so there's no worry of bad data. I can work with their name (surname + name) if I mess around in other places, so this works for my purposes. Thanks! It would be *nice* to have surname only, but full name is fine too.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex.

```
^.*\|([^\d]+)[^|]*$
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/lrK5Po/2)

**Code**

```
System.out.println(s.replaceAll("^.*\\|([^\\d]+)[^|]*$", "$1"));
```

**Output**

```
Sauer Meredith                                                                                                                                                                  
Roberts Westley                                                                                                                                                                 
Haag Camille                                                                                                                                                                    
Trantow Danielle                                                                                                                                                                
Wiza Bell
```

Complete Code : https://ideone.com/uON0BP

Answer (score 0):

I would use [Regular Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for this.

**Code:**

```
@Test
public void test() {
  String[] lines
    = ("40327 Ocie Camp Apt. 117, Maywood|1-155-932-2562 x738|Sauer Meredith\n" +
       "76106 Tomas Highway, Santa Ana|722.884.5632|Roberts Westley")
          .split("\n");

  Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("^(?<address>.*?)\\|(?<number>.*?)\\|(?<surname>.*?) (?<name>.*?)$");
  for (String line : lines) {
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(line);
    if(matcher.find()) {
      String surname = matcher.group("surname");
      System.out.println(surname);
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

> Sauer
>   Roberts

---

The expression matches a single line in the format you have given and you can then easily access the single parts of the string that you need.

This is also more easy to maintain if you want to access different parts in the future.

Answer (score 0):

**Use `lastIndexOf` method**

> This method returns the index of the last occurrence of the character in the character sequence represented by this object that is less than or equal to fromIndex, or -1 if the character does not occur before that point.

Example :

```
String data = "40327 Ocie Camp Apt. 117, Maywood|1-155-932-2562 x738|Sauer Meredith";
System.out.println(data.substring(data.lastIndexOf('|') + 1));
```

Answer (score 0):

That's a job for regular expressions:

```
    Pattern rx = Pattern.compile("[^\\|]*\\|[^\\|]*\\|\\s*([^0-9]+)");

    String line = "76106 Tomas Highway, Santa Ana|722.884.5632|Roberts Westley 19056";

    Matcher m = rx.matcher(line);
    if(m.find()){
      String surname = m.group(1).trim();
      System.out.println(surname);
    }
```

This will output

```
Roberts Westley
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one out. It will give you just surname.

```
String address = "40327 Ocie Camp Apt. 117, Maywood|1-155-932-2562 x738|Sauer Meredith";
System.out.println(address.substring(address.indexOf("|", address.indexOf("|") + 1) + 1, address.length()).split(" ")[0]);
```